# Reproject data on a regular world map

Tags: qgis

I am experiencing this issue (Fig.1)[image: Data]
Basically, it seems that my data (red dots) are only partially falling on the world shapefile. Both the layers are projected in WGS 84 EPSG: 4326.
How can I solve the issue?
Shall I reproject the data or find a world shapefile that is showed in a different way?
Sorry for the non-technical language but I find difficult to explain the specific issue.

Comment: There must be some projection  mistake somewhere. Are both your data set initially in WGS 84 or are they -  or at least one of them reprojected in qgis? Is the point data set read in as a geo data set or is it read in from a text file or excel file or similiar?

Comment: The issue with the points going too far to the east can be solved by subtracting 360 from all longitudes > 180.

Comment: Also, is it possible to upload at least a part of your point data set somewhere? If you upload a part of it, it needs to be a part with coastlines, eg use Scandinavia, since there you have a coastline with a lot of details. You can delete all attributes from the dataset except for the coordinates.

Comment: What software are you using? What is your source for the world shapefile? There are actually two issues.  1.  as Morten Sickel stated, your world shapefile appears to use longitude from -180 to 180 and your points 0 to 360.  2.  The points and world shapefile seem to be misaligned from 0-180 longitude.